# Problems with looping a json

Tags: php, json, loops

Here I have a json which i get after making a request to the twitter API. I have already seen different working examples of looping a json. Even I have do it in another projects. But this time it isn't working.

I've tested a lot of things. I guess it's normal it doesn't work for now. The variable arrayFriends isn't even being used. Just i was testing some moves.

Don't know exactly where I am failing. I would like to have some feedback

Thank you guys!

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json';
$getfield = '?screen_name=J7mb0';
$requestMethod = 'GET';


$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$json = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(true, array(CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem'));
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(true, array(CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem'));



$arrayFriends = var_dump(json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));

$json = json_decode($json, true);

echo $json;

foreach($json->ids as $obj){
   echo $obj->ids;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [**json_decode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with `true`, the returned value will be an **array**, not an object.
Therefore, you won't be able to use the property-access method here:

```
 foreach($json->ids as $obj){
```

You have to use the array-access method instead:

```
 foreach($json['ids'] as $obj){
```

or, change the parameter at decoding, so you get an object:

```
 $json = json_decode($json, false);
 // or just simply:
 // $json = json_decode($json);
 // since the second parameter defaults to FALSE
```

ALSO, `$arrayFriends` will remain empty, because var_dump **returns nothing** at all.

```
// Change this:
// $arrayFriends = var_dump(json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));
// ...to this:
$arrayFriends = json_decode($json, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked! After trying different things it started working.

Actually I'm trying to access another json but this isn't working. It is the same app but with more content.

```
$user = 'seyroku';

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json';
$getfield = '?screen_name='.$user.'';
$requestMethod = 'GET';


$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$json = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(true, array(CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem'));



$arrayFriends = json_decode($json, true,512,JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

foreach($arrayFriends['ids'] as $obj){
   echo $obj,",";

$url2 = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json';
$getfield2 = '?user_id='.$obj.'';

$json2 = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield2)
->buildOauth($url2, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(true, array(CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem'));

  echo  $twitter->setGetfield($getfield2)
->buildOauth($url2, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(true, array(CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem'));

  $json3 = json_decode($json2, true);

  foreach ($json3['name'] as $nombre) {
      echo $nombre,",";
  }


   /* $sql = "INSERT INTO friendtest (user, friends)
 VALUES ('$user' , '$obj' )";

 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
 }*/

}
```

The first for each it returns me the id properly. But the second one which I expect to give me the name of that id doesn't do it. I tried different things but still isn't working.

Could you give me some feedback?

Sorry guys for being so bad at this.